# CSS3 Donut Chart

Tags: css, svg

I have created a fiddle of a simple donut chart: http://jsfiddle.net/4azpfk3r/217/

How can i get the donut chart to have a red outline and the score/percentage filled to be solid red leaving a transparent/red outlined section of percentage not scored?

CSS:

```
.background {
    background: grey;
}

.item {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}


.item h2 {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
}


svg {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}


.circle_animation {
    stroke-dasharray: 440;
    stroke-dashoffset: 440;
}


.html .circle_animation {
    -webkit-animation: html 1s ease-out forwards;
    animation: html 1s ease-out forwards;
}


.css .circle_animation {
    -webkit-animation: css 1s ease-out forwards;
    animation: css 1s ease-out forwards;
}


@-webkit-keyframes html {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 80;
    }
}


@keyframes html {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 80;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, try adding this line of css:

`#circle{fill:none;stroke:red;color:red}`

For the score type to also be in red, add a color property to the h2:

```
.item h2 {
   text-align:center;
   position: absolute;
   line-height: 125px;
   width: 100%;
   color:red; /*ADD RED COLOR TO SCORE*/
}
```

To style the Score header, first give it a class:
`<p class="scoreHeader">Score: 76/100</p>`

And style it as you wish:

```
.scoreHeader{
    padding:10px;
    background:red;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Ok, that makes the line red... But i want the score achieved red, and the whole donut with a red outline.

Comment: @OamPsy Are you saying you want the circle to go all the way around?

Comment: @OamPsy Please accept answer if it solved your problem =)

Answer (score 0):

Check my example here https://codepen.io/350d/pen/gxXyGB
The idea is to utilize just a `border-color` and `rotation`. No gradients and animations used here.